# Is static URL better than dynamic URL in terms of SERP?

Tags: wordpress, seo

I've been reading up on SEO and how to construct my links in terms of getting better SERP.

I'm using WordPress as the framework for my site and have custom templates retrieving data from my DB.

What makes a URL dynamic, is the usage of `?` and `&`. Nothing more, nothing less. Google recommends that I should not have too many attributes in my URL - and that's understandable.

Dynamic: `www.mysite.com/?id=123&name=some+store+name&city=london`
Static: `www.mysite.com/london/some+store+name/123`

Q1: I don't feel that adding the store ID in this static URL looks nice. But I do need it in order to fetch data from the DB, right?

Reading various blogs, I see many SEO (experts) saying different things, but I feel most of it is just talk without actually proving their statements. We can all agree that static URLs are good in terms of usability (and readability).

Q2: But many claim that static URLs prevent duplicate content. I don't agree on that as all my contents have unique ID. Can anyone comment on this?

Q3: In the end, for the Google search engine (and others) it really doesn't matter if the URL is static or dynamic. But since Google is working towards user friendly content, is that the only argument for having static URLs?

Answer (score 1):

1) There's no problem using DB ids alongside static URLs. Many huge e-commerce and other commercial sites do this (Amazon, eBay... hell, everyone really.)

2) A static URL in and of itself does not prevent duplicate content. There are hundreds of ways duplicates can happen (child pages, external copy, javascript, form fields, ajax, archive sections... the list foes on.)

3) It doesn't matter if it's static or dynamic for indexing. But in terms of ranking well, static URLs with informative (and relevant to the targeted keywords) searches are hugely beneficial. Multivariate testing I've done shows users are also generally re-assured by clean looking URLs in terms of usability.

If you give me some more examples, I can probably help out a bit more.

Answer (score 1):

Urls without parameters are always better. It won't absolutely kill SEO - but it is better not to have them.

!0 years ago Google would ignore parameters and would penalize you for URLs with parameters. Today they are really good at figuring out these db parameters - but not perfect. Among other things Google has to try to figure out which URL parameters matter, and which don't and if parameter order matters.

E.g. you may have URL parameters that store user preferences, navigation state etc. This will just proliferate URLs that Google has to try to decode. So what you should do is:

1. Right before generating an URL at least sort your parameters.
2. Convert parameters that matter into things that don't look like parameters. So if I had a shoe store with a urls like http://mystore.com/mypage?category=boots&brand=great&color=red I'd rewrite that to something like http://mystore.com/mypage/category/boots/brand/great/color/red or even better:
   http://myscore.com/mypage/boots/great/red

Then you can add the parameters that don't matter for the page content at the end. Google will figure out they don't matter.

The other reason to fix your URLs is that Goolge displays them to users in the SERP, and people are more likely to click on readable URLs than database URLs.

Why do big stores like amazon use database urls? because they are giant, bad urls don't hurt them, and their systems are so large and complex it is the only way to manage it. But for smaller sites with fewer products, readble URLs are achievable and are one of the few advantages a small site can have over a big one.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. How would you go about managing id's? would you use http://myscore.com/mypage/boots/great/red?id=34 ?

Comment: Does id=34 identify the whole page? If it does I would do this: http://myscore.com/34/whatever-you/want-here just so long as you canonical everything after 34 to the same thing. E.g. if you also have /34/other-stuff/here add a rel canonical to http://myscore.com/34/whatever-you/want-here

Comment: basically do exactly what stackoverflow.com is doing. Note that their urls are questions/id/random-stuff-here. You can change everything after the id and the same page still comes up.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone observing closely Google SERP results definitely find some part of SERP results are highlighted and bold as well. Now noticing further one can easily find "Search Query" are getting highlighted or bold in "Title" , "Descriptions" and "URL" who are using same "Search Query" in Title, Descriptions and URL as well.

Now thing is if any website URL's are dynamic and coming with parameter ID, they are loosing keywords from Title, Descriptions and URL as well.

Ex:

http://www.johnzaccheofineart.com/catagory-2/?id=4

http://www.johnzaccheofineart.com/painting/johnzaccheo

Sample Search : Painting for Sale

Now easily we can understand difference between static and dynamic URL performance. One URL coming with such word which has no search value, other URL is coming with category name as well as painter name.

So, being a user i will give preference to 2nd one which is understandable from URL itself.